# Can I use my regular 3.5 mm earphones with an iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ear-phones

The earphones that I have received with my iPhone have 4 metal connector jack. By the size of it, it looks 3.5 mm in diameter. Unfortunately, the white earphones are not of the in-ear type and slip out from my ears quite frequently.

I have a different set of Sony earphones with a 3.5 mm jack. It has 3 metal connectors which means that if I insert it in the iPhone, at least I am shorting out 2 metals receptors on the iPhone female. Is it fine to do such a thing? My guess is that if the short is occurring between the mic and the ground, it should be fine as usually not a lot of current is sourced to a mic. I was just looking around for more information. A connection diagram would be great.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you can use any earphones with a 3.5mm audio jack. I'm surprised you did not just try it out :)

I thought I'd add some additional background information I just read about in a report on yet another Apple-Samsung patent case, Apple [holds a patent](http://www.google.com/patents/US7912501?dq=7,912,501) on an audio jack which has the circuitry to detect the type of headphones plugged in, and I can only assume this is what they actually use in their iPhones.

Comment: The original iPhone was the only one that had a problem with certain headphones, because the headphone jack was recessed and if the headphones had a bulky plug, they wouldn't fit. But everything since then has been just dandy and standard.

Answer (score 0):

Some earphones are not supported by iphone...
I've try some earphones but the bass of the music didn't exist.. So i prefer to use apple earphones ^^

Comment: Most earphones, if not all, work perfectly with the iPhone. Perhaps it was a problem with the connector on your earphones that prevented the bass from working?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah. All the headphones that you have are 3.5mm but if you can look closely, the white one has 3 black strips a.k.a. the 4-conductor TRRS while the Sony one has 2 black strips a.k.a. the 3-conductor TRRS. So, the iPhone only supports those headphones with the 4-conductor, for example, the Beats headphones.

Reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phone_connector_(audio)

Comment: Your answer starts by saying yes but at the end says no - which is the correct answer